# DialogFragment keeps data in memory, even after dismiss() is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am having a very odd behaviour here. From my `MainActivity` class, I invoke my `DialogFragment`:

```
EndRoundDialogFragment df = new EndRoundDialogFragment(myVO);
df.show(fragmentManager, "end_round_dialog_fragment");
```

The constructor for this DialogFragment is simple:

```
public EndRoundDialogFragment(UserVO vo) {
    this.userVO = vo;
}
```

This Fragment has a Google Maps fragment inside it. So what I basically do is:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.end_round_dialog, container, false);

    mMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_result)).getMap();
    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);

    buttonClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onEndDialogClosed();
            userVO = null;
            dismissAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    });

//Rest of the code is manipulating Markers in this map.
```

So, when user clicks on Close button, I dismiss the dialog and am OKwith State loss. I am even setting the VO to null.

As you can see, my `Activity` implements the Dialog's Listener `onEndDialogClosed()`. This method implementation is:

```
@Override
public void onEndDialogClosed() {
    Fragment prev = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("end_round_dialog_fragment");
    if(prev != null)
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(prev).commit();
    new Get5PointsTask().execute();
}
```

So I am also removing the whole fragment when it is closed.

I also added the following to this DialogFragments, to make sure that the Google Maps fragment was indeed being removed from the code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Fragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_result);
    if (f != null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
}
```

While debugging, I verified that the variable `f` is not null and the `remove()` code is indeed called.

When I instantiate the `DialogFragment` again, with a new VO data, Google Maps is shown with **new and old data.** It's just not resetting the de memory...

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

And I found what the problem was. Was simply not erasing my VO in the Activity's `onEndDialogClosed()` method. Stupid me.

Thanks to all and hope this code helps other people.

Comment: please write an answer instead of an edit, so that people can see it as a resolved and use it accordingly.

Comment: myVO = new UserVO(); That was my fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed the issue.
I was simply not re-instantiating the VO that held the user data in the `Activity`... so when opening the `DialogFragment`, it held the new and the old that. Simple like that, stupid like that.

Thanks!